# what do musicians do if they want to take a vacation?

Tags: practice

let's say you wanted to take a 3 month vacation

How would you 'keep practicing?'

I mean you don't just forget everything but won't you feel like 'ugh' once you get back on your instrument?

Comment: See: http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/4151/what-instruments-are-inexpensive-portable-and-not-too-loud

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's going to depend a lot on the destination. A violinist or guitarist wouldn't want to take their instrument into the jungle for even a few days. And the pianist...

If possible they would find somewhere to play. I used to go to the Canaries a lot, and found some nice schools of music - with instruments, of course. Went to Russia years ago, ended up buying a guitar to keep practising.

A lot of musos have at least one other instrument to play. Often, I'll put a clarinet or flute into the suitcase, small enough, and quiet enough to use almost anywhere.

Depending on the destination, (and genre!) there may well be a band, orchestra or open mic venue that could be explored even before the sojourn takes place.

You're right - an edge is usually lost with that sort of time away - trumpeter's lip, fluidity, reading, chords not so frequently played on guitar, but it soon (hopefully) comes back. But most musos would want to have their dose of music at a frequent level.

And let's not forget, he'll have his music to listen to, and maybe some dots to follow on the Ipad.

Comment: Second this, if I went on a long vacation I'd have harmonicas and a flute in my luggage, and my budget would certainly include a cheap nylon string in local currency which I'd sell or give away before leaving.  Not just to stay sharp, but because 3 months without instruments doesn't sound like much of a holiday to me!

Comment: also I know a fiddler who has a decent enough Chinese "travel fiddle" which she takes with her to gigs in more precarious locations.  I have a nice second hand student flute I use for jazz gigs where I know I'm likely to have a couple of drinks and probably leave it on a table somewhere at some point.  Obviously I wouldn't be pleased if something happened to it, but it would be a lot less of a night ruiner than if something happened to my main instrument.

Answer (score 7):

Most musicians take a small instrument with them when on holiday, but even if you don't, you still have your voice. As long as you have a way to record or transcribe then you can still practice and learn.

I often find that a few days away from my main instrument really helps me change my improvisation structure, so I like to listen to a lot of different music on holiday. That stuff I don't usually hear makes its way into my head and when I return it comes out in my playing.

Answer (score 2):

If you're a serious professional musician you just DON'T take a day off practicing, let alone a month.   If your standards (or those of your employer) are lower, you just cope.  Yes, your playing will drop.  Yes, it will come back.

Comment: It sounds just hard to make music for living.... sounds as hard as an athlete.

Comment: @Aminopterin  you're starting to get the idea...

Comment: Actually, there are plenty of niches for a professional musician that don't involve virtuoso-level performance. Just be at a level where what is required isn't hard FOR YOU.

Comment: not all musicians are strictly musicians by career. Some do it next to their main career.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this also depends on how bad you want it. If you simply play as a hobby, it may be good to take a hiatus to return with fresh creative inspiration and yearning to play.

For the die-hard, there's so many options with modern technology. For the pianist:

[image: portable keys]

Funny story: my mentor, in the days before the technology pictured above, made this little board with a 2 octave run of piano keys. He had ingeniously carved the board and attached the keys in a way that perfectly mimicked a piano's action. Of course, it didn't produce sound... But, he constructed it for the explicit purpose of being able to practice fingering while on vacation/holiday. He'd continue to use it after that - even driving down the road. :P

Yo-Yo Ma [buys an extra plane ticket for his cello](http://www.nytimes.com/1981/05/24/arts/when-a-virtuoso-and-his-cello-take-to-the-road.html?pagewanted=all) when he flies.

A professional will sometimes ship their instruments to the destination, when they can't be carried. One can almost certainly line up a gig or two in order to cover any transit costs (playing music is never 'work' for some of us.)

I have basses in the homes of select friends and family for when I visit, so I don't have to carry around my main squeeze...

Or purchase something inexpensive at the destination, as Tim says.

Comment: oh, I didn't know this even existed, that's so cool

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a pro but I have a cheap guitar and mini practice amp and headphones that I take with me, as well as a portable digital piano with a decent feel. I do spend two weeks away from my main gear every year but again, I'm not a pro. Also those two weeks I spend at the beach but at a rental cottage that has air conditioning so it's ok for wood and electronics.